# Confused about creating a "login" form

Tags: php, html

So what I want to do it kind of like a login form, but rather than it being individual users, it's more of a password locked page.
Here's sort of what I have for php

```
<?php
$user = $_POST['user'];

if($user == "placeholder")
{
        include("randomfile.html");
}
else
{
    if(isset($_POST))
    {?>

            <form id="login" method="POST">
            User <input type="text" name="user" id="userID"></input><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"></input>
            </form>
    <?}
}
?>
```

and it's basically doing what I want it to do, but if you were to go back (like use the go back button in the browser) it doesn't get rid of that submitted text (in this case, it would be "placeholder").

Any suggestions of any other way to do this, maybe easier or more basic because I just started with php, and is it possible so that if you enter "placeholder" and submit it, then go back, it doesn't have the User field already filled out with what you previously submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form id="login" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
```

That work for all the form, I think is the easiest. Ref: [form:autocomplete](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_autocomplete.asp)